# NextEPC on OpenStack(Microstack)

Tags: openstack, microstack

I have the openstack (microstack) environment where I have an Ubuntu Instance. Instance has both Internal and floating IP. I installed NextEPC there and bound the MME to Internal IP. I have an eNB(hardware) where I set the floating IP as MME address. But, the connectivity is not getting established between the MME and eNB. Is my configuration okay in this case? If not what should I do? I would be happy to see the expert's suggestions.
N.B. eNB's and Instance's floating IPs are from same network.
A lot of thanks.

Comment: While I know nothing about NextEPC and how communication between eNB and MME works, I assume TCP or UDP is used. If so, I suggest you first confirm that NextEPC port(s) are open in the instance's security groups. Next, check connectivity to the instance via floating IP. You could run `tcpdump` on the instance to see if traffic from the eNB arrives. Next steps depend on your findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already come up with this issue. All I needed to add an SCTP security rule in the openstack environment. The protocol between eNB and MME is SCTP.By default there is no sctp rule in the openstack security group.